# Zombie.js options not permitted any more?

Tags: node.js, testing, zombie.js

I am making a simple testing script using Node.js and Zombie.js for a website of mine. I wanted to make it so that the 'visits' are comming from chrome:

```
var UA = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36"

setInterval(function () {
        browser.visit('/', {userAgent: UA}, function(err) {
                assert.ifError(err);
        });
}, 1000);
```

This seems to work but the problem is that for every request made I get this error in the console:

```
visit with options is deprecated and will be removed soon
```

Now, is there a more 'correct' way to do this with Zombie.js? Or, is there another option for me to use (like Phantomjs perjhaps)?

Any ideas?

Comment: try settings the options globally http://zombie.labnotes.org/API

Comment: @Giannis Make it an answer and I shall upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the options globally.

[zombie.labnotes.org/API](http://zombie.labnotes.org/API)

Comment: Content and URL has been changed.